# Java helloworldswt tutorial doesn't work

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I am new to Java/SWT/Eclipse and trying to learn SWT and I am having difficulties to get the following code working.Can someone help ?

### Code:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;

import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class HelloHelloSWT {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setText("Hello world!");
        shell.open();
        while(!shell.isDisposed()){
            display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
        shell.close();
    }}
```

Well I tried running it the same way as the first tutorial, but this error popped up:

### Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
    no swt-win32-4333 in java.library.path
    no swt-win32 in java.library.path
    Can't load library: C:\Users\sdp0121\.swt\lib\win32\x86\swt-win32-4333.dll
    Can't load library: C:\Users\sdp0121\.swt\lib\win32\x86\swt-win32.dll

    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(C.java:21)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:138)
    at HelloHelloSWT.main(HelloHelloSWT.java:8)
```

Comment: There is a discussion about this on the Eclipse forums [here](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/261606/)

Answer (score 0):

Go back to the step of the tutorial titled "Configure the Java project". Then go into the project Properties and select Java Build Path then expand the reference to the SWT project (small triangle before the project name). If it says "None", click Edit and find the SWT project in my workspace.
Hope this helps.